# Format numeric string

Tags: javascript, php, preg-replace

I've the following **string** (meaning it's not numeric):

```
"0870490055012000000000"
```

wich is always 22 characters long. I need to transform into:

```
"087.049.0055.0120.0000.0000"
```

Using PHP or even on js/client side.

I found something like [this](http://www.oficinadanet.com.br/artigo/php/mascara-de-formatacao-em-php) but was not able to solve the problem.

---

I guess there are many ways to solve this. I'm just asking for something like:

```
$x= format("00000", "xxx.xxx..xxx.x.x.x")
```

or

```
$x = preg_replace("/a;;w.;w;e;ew")
```

Comment: Is it always 22 chars long?

Comment: And what have you tried??

Comment: @Rudie Yes, 22 char long always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with PHP, you can use this:

```
$str = preg_replace('~\A\d{3}\K\d{3}|\d{4}~', '.$0', $str);
```

where `\A` is an anchor for the start of the string.

`\K` removes all that have been matched on the left from match result.

If you need something more general to apply a mask to a string, the link you shared in your question will give you the way to do.